# JFrame showing one panel but not showing another

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, panel

Hey guys I am creating a JFrame and I have created 2 panels.  The first one is in the center with 3 buttons in a row and the second one is in the south with 3 buttons in a row.  The frame is only showing the last panel made.  It is like it creates the first panel and then overwrites it with the second panel.  Here is my code:

```
private JPanel getSouthPanel()
{
  JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  panel1.add(button1, BorderLayout.WEST);
  panel1.add(button2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  panel1.add(button3, BorderLayout.EAST);
  return panel1;
}

private JPanel getCenterPanel()
{
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  panel.add(button1, BorderLayout.WEST);
  panel.add(button2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  panel.add(button3, BorderLayout.EAST);
  return panel;
}

public void layoutComponents()
{
  Container container = frame.getContentPane();
  container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  container.add(getCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
  container.add(getSouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  frame.setSize(300, 300);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can't put the same buttons in two different panels, you will need to create separate buttons for each panel.